# Scripts Problem

Tags: unity

Good evening. I have a problem, the script for changing the color of the object does not work. Throws out of Game mode. I don't understand what the problem is?
[image]
[image]
Below is the script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ColorPicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("ColorSettings Canvas")]
    public GameObject ColorSettingsCanvas;
    public GameObject Color1Button;
    public GameObject Color2Button;
    public GameObject Color3Button;
    public GameObject Color4Button;
    public GameObject Color5Button;
    public GameObject Color6Button;
    public Material[] BodyColorMat;
    Material CurrMat;
    Renderer renderer;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

//render color1
public void Color1()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[0];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}

//render color2
public void Color2()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[1];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}

//render color3
public void Color3()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[2];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}


//render color4
public void Color4()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[3];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}
//render color5
public void Color5()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[4];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}
//render color6
public void Color6()
{
    renderer.material = BodyColorMat[5];
    CurrMat = renderer.material;
}
```

}

Comment: Change Renderer to MeshRenderer and it should work

Comment: Assets\Scripts\ColorPicker.cs(18,20): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Renderer' to 'UnityEngine.MeshRenderer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @JohannesAndersson `MeshRenderer` is a subclass of `Renderer`, so it will be returned from `GetComponent<Renderer>()` just fine. It could be that `Color2()` is getting invoked before this script has had a chance to run its `Start()` method (since it seems to be inactive in the hierarchy in the provided screenshot), or that there is another copy of this script in the scene that does not have a `MeshRenderer` attached.

Comment: @DMGregory You're correct, thank you for the clarification.